# cx_Freeze, "ImportError DLL load failed"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, exe

He creado un código de una interfaz con *Tkinter*, *reportlab*, *openpyxl* entre otros. Todo dentro de mi archivo .py funciona muy bien pero al momento de crear un ejecutable (.exe) con ***cx_Freeze*** se presenta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda. :D

El **setup.py** que hice es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola.He logrado que funcione pero ahora tengo el siguiente inconveniente y no se como solucionarlo, gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Karen deberías añadir tu `setup.py`, suele deberse a que cx_Freeze no es capaz de resolver las dependencias, en concreto de encontrar `tcl86t.dll` y `tk86t.dll` por lo general situadas en la carpeta `DLLs` del directorio de instalación de Python.

Comment: Karen no debes usar los comentarios para agregar información a la pregunta. Añadelo a la pregunta en sí, usa el botón `editar` que hay debajo de ella.

Comment: Ya lo agregue, gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Te falta incluir ambos ficheros dll, en tu caso se supone que deben estar situados en:

> C:\Program Files\Python35-32\DLLs

Comprueba que existe este directorio y que contiene los archivos:

> tk86t.dll
>   tcl86t.dll

El siguiente **setup.py** no debería dar ningún problema (probado en *Python 3.5 y 3.6* con *cx_Freeze 5.0.2* y una app simple en *Tkinter* en *Windows 10*.):

```
import os
import sys
import cx_Freeze

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')



include_files = [os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
                 os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll')]

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("programa1.py",
                                    base = "Win32GUI",
                                    icon = None)]

options = {"build_exe": {"packages": [],
                         "includes": [],
                         "include_files": include_files
                         }
           }

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "PDF",
    version = "1.0",
    description = "Formulario a PDF",
    options = options,
    executables = executables)
```

Asegúrate que al ejecutar `setup.py build` en CMD llamas al intérprete adecuado (importante si tienes distintas versiones de Python instaladas), en tu caso debería ser:

```
py -3.5-32 setup.py build
```

o directamente:

```
"C:\Program Files\Python35-32\python" setup.py build
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda me funcionó pero ahora tengo otro problema que no se como solucionar.Lo dejo en la pregunta gracias. :3